# CSS UL LI menu does not work after some hover action

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I designed a vertical menu using CSS, `li` and `ul` tags. It works fine, but just for many hints. After some time, hover effect works just for the last item.
Please look at my project here: http://www.saberi.ws/test/
Please move your mouse on the menu in the left side (Products, Countries, ...) to see this in action.

You can see related CSS file [here](http://www.saberi.ws/test/css/main.css).

Comment: Try removing the JavaScript to see if that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#ticker` is lying in front of your navigation. Add `z-index: 0` to your `#ticker` and add `position: relative; z-index: 1` to your `#container_left_menu`.

This will move your navigation over your ticker. The `position: relative` is neccessary, because `z-index` does only work with `position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

My solution is much simpler, to my mind. Simply add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#news`.